# Incrementation in a model doesnt work

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I want to increment an attribute of a model. But it does not take the incrementation into account.Here is the code. This part is inside the model function:

```
for objt in CompanyHomePageLogosWaiting.objects.filter(score=2):
    if self.logo_name==objt.logo_name:
        if self.test < self.score :
            num = self.score
            self.test += 1 #### this is the incrementation
        if self.test == self.score :
            objt.score=-1
            objt.save()
            self.test = 0
return num
```

test is an attribute of the model with default=-1.
Thanks.

Comment: A.How is this recursive?
B. You are returning inside the for loop, you'll never get to the second object in CompanyHomePageLogosWaiting.objects.filter(score=2)
C. You only assign a value to num in case self.test < self.score, otherwise youre returning an unassigned var

Comment: the return is not in the for loop. I formated badly. In the case you are talking, I want self.test to be incremented by 1.

Comment: and I have initialize num to 0. As I said it is just a part of the code that I thought is relevant for my problem.

Comment: how do you verify `test` isn't increased?

Comment: I'm thinking that you are incrementing `self.test` while it is `< self.score` but then you set it to `0` once it is `== self.score`, which I assume happens eventually.

Comment: @doru I have commented the instruction and affected 16 to self.test. In the output it is indeed 16. But in the incrematation case nothing.

Comment: I have understood the problem.It doesnt save the value of test in the database. Now I am looking for a way to force it save the value in the db.